# Produce an xslt output in a specific order

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a large xml document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Data>
  <aTable>
    <aTableRow Col1="1" Col2="someText"/>
    <aTableRow Col1="2" Col2="newText"/>
    ...
  </aTable>
  <anotherTable>
    <anotherTableRow Col3="someText" Col4="42"/>
    <anotherTableRow Col3="myText" Col4="34"/>
    ...
  </anotherTable>
  ...
</Data>
```

I needed to transform the document in a corresponding sequence of SQL INSERT statement. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO aTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES (1, "someText")
```

I already have the transformation from a "table" to the corresponding SQL statement, but the xslt output is generated in the same order of the document.

Is there a way to have for example anotherTable before aTable?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments and answer. Reading them I realized that my original question wasn't that clear. I'll try to add more detail.

I have produced a template that correctly transform xml data in a sequence of insert statements suppose that this template is named "insertGeneration".

then i wrote something like:

```
<xsl:template match="Data/anotherTable">
  <xsl:call-template name="insertGeneration"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data/aTable">
  <xsl:call-template name="insertGeneration"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I expected the output to be generated in this order, i.e. all `INSERT INTO anotherTable` before all `INSERT INTO aTable`. But the resulting order is the same of the source document.

I need a specific order otherwise I could violate foreign key constraints when executing SQL script.

My xslt processor is Visual Studio 2005. Well, not properly a compact xslt processor ;-)

Comment: It would help to see your current transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="Data">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*">
    <xsl:sort select="name(..)" case-order="lower-first" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data/*/*">
  <xsl:text>INSERT INTO [</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name(..)" />
  <xsl:text>] (</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="names" />
  <xsl:text>) VALUES (</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="values" />
  <xsl:text>)&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data/*/*/@*" mode="names">
  <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
  <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data/*/*/@*" mode="values">
  <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
  <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
    <xsl:with-param name="search">'</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="replace">''</xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Which produces T-SQL compatible output, like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO [anotherTable] ([Col3], [Col4]) VALUES ('someText', '42')
INSERT INTO [anotherTable] ([Col3], [Col4]) VALUES ('myText', '34')
INSERT INTO [aTable] ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES ('1', 'some''Text')
INSERT INTO [aTable] ([Col1], [Col2]) VALUES ('2', 'newText')
```

Tweak the code to your DB's syntax if necessary.

This uses lexicographical order by table name. If you want a different order, either change the `<xsl:sort>` accordingly or use several separate `<xsl:apply-templates>` to produce the wanted sequence. (Be aware, some XSLT processors seem to ignore the `case-order` parameter.)

Note that `string-replace` is a named template that implements a string replacement function (necessary for XSLT 1.0). If you have XSLT 2.0 you could simply use the built-in `string-replace()` function.

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace">
  <xsl:param name="subject" select="string()" />
  <xsl:param name="search" />
  <xsl:param name="replace" />

  <xsl:variable name="head" select="substring-before($subject, $search)" />
  <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after($subject, $search)" />
  <xsl:variable name="found" select="$head or $tail" />

  <xsl:if test="not($found)">
    <xsl:value-of select="$subject" />
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="$found">
    <xsl:value-of select="$head" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$replace" />
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="subject" select="$tail" />
      <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$search" />
      <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and useful answer, but this was not what I intended. It's my fault the question was not very clear. I'll try to improve it...

Comment: Even if you won't use the rest of my answer, you can use the obvious pointer to `<xsl:sort>`, can't you? Both `<xsl:apply-templates>` and `<xsl:for-each>` can be sorted.

Comment: Yes but the sort is not alphabetical I need the output to be sorted in order that, when I launch the resulting SQL script, I don't violate any foreign key constraint

Comment: And how on earth should XSLT know what that order is?

Comment: I understand XSLT can't but I know that order. I tought I can force somehow that order changing the order of template processing

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but only if you can formulate a rule to infer the correct order from your XML file. Preferably a rule that does not involve magic. ;-)

Comment: Something like manually reorder the source XML document? ;-) There is really nothing more magical? ;-)

Comment: If your input XML comes in any arbitrary order, contains any arbitrary table names and no technical clue as to how these depend on each other, then I don't see how XSLT could ever be able to figure this out. I mean, if *you* can't explain it, nobody can implement it.